# How to create a 3*3 Matrix Grid in android

Tags: android

I want to make a simple Sudoku game in which i want to create 3*3 matrix.I created a matrix but i getting problem how to insert some value at specific position in Grid Layout.Please can anyone help me.

I have done up to this so far...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    mScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

    mGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
    //  mGrid.setOnDragListener(new DragListener());

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < NBR_ITEMS; i++) {
        final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, mGrid, false);
        final TextView text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        if ((i == 4)) {

            text.setText("3");

        }
        if ((i == 2)) {

            text.setText("2");

        }
        if ((i == 7)) {

            text.setText("1");

        }


        final int size = mGrid.getChildCount();
        System.out.println("size===" + size);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int index = calculateNewIndex(itemView.getX(), itemView.getY());
                System.out.println("index====" + index);


                System.out.println("click on cell");
            }
        });

        //  itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new LongPressListener());
        mGrid.addView(itemView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Table Layout

Comment: What have you done yourself?

Comment: @Bartek Lipinski i have created a 3*3 matrix using Grid Layout  and Card View.But  the thing is i want to insert the values at specific positions .

Comment: @RishikeshRahi let me rephrase that: Can you post the code of yours?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can create 3*3 matrix using LinearLayout and do wahtever you want like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZAhk.png)

Comment: @ Nivesh thanks for your answer but the thing is i have to use Grid Layout. I am implementing Sudoku game.

Comment: Yes i know but this is simpler then grid layout you can maintain all screen sizes with this one layout.Simply set the background or text of textView.